# Shell script not able to parse a string under if statement

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have a simple script in which I am trying to find if make some_target exists or not. In case it does not exist then print a statement and exit 1.

```
#!/bin/bash
set +ex
output=$(make -n some_target 2>&1 | head -1)
echo "$output"
if [ "$output" == "*No rule to make target*" ]; then
  echo "Target is not Present"
  exit 1
else
  echo "foo"  
fi
```

but it is throwing an error and going into else loop

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'some_target'.  Stop.
test.sh: 5: [: make: *** No rule to make target 'some_target'.  Stop.: unexpected operato                                                                                                  
foo
```

Comment: echo "$output" before you use it. I also suspect the asterisks in the test are being expanded as filename wildcards: note the some_target in the error message. They should be inside the quotes, not outside.

Comment: It doesnt makes any difference, updated Question and output above

Comment: You are `test`ing for an exact match which there is not. That's why the `else` branch is taken. Try comparing to the exact message.

Comment: Right hand value may change so it is more of finding a substring inside a bigger string

Comment: `*` will be literal if quoted.

Comment: Are you thinking that the `*` means any character? It does not in this context.

Comment: I suspect the *error* is because (in spite of the `#!/bin/bash` shebang) you are running the script using `sh` - in which `==` is not a valid string comparison operator (it should be a single `=`)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find an answer with below:

```
#!/bin/sh
set +ex 
if make -n some_target 2>&1 | grep -m 1 "No rule to make target"; then
        echo "Target is not Present"
        exit 1
else
        echo "foo"
fi
```

Comment: `set +ex` is not needed as those shell options wouldn't be set by default anyway. The `-m 1` option to `grep` could be replaced by `-q` unless you want to see the output of `grep`.

Comment: Thanks that would also work

Answer (score 0):

Pattern matching(*) is possible in [`bash` logical operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs) `==`, `=`, and `!=` where the operand on the right is considered a pattern. So you can write your condition:

```
if [[ $output == *'No rule to make target'* ]]
```

to check if the answer contains `No rule to make target`.

This said, it could be more efficient to check the return code of `make`?

(*) This is the same basic pattern matching as done on file names. There is also a  logical operator `=~` that takes a regular expression.